# Different behaviour of pgfplots xticks and extra x ticks

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I am having some issues with extra x ticks in semilogarithm plot.
I want to add few extra ticks to x axis but then x ticks are overlayed with the extra ticks 10^ potential.

[image: x axis without extra ticks]

[image: x axis with extra x ticks]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\usepackage{relsize}

\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}
}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xmin=0.06 ,xmax = 60, domain = 0.2:60,
    height = 8 cm ,
    width = 8 cm,
    xlabel = {Sieve opening, (mm)},
    ylabel ={Sieve passing, (\%)},
    grid = both,
    %
    yticklabel pos=left,
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    extra x tick  style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd,
        every tick label/.style={
        font=\tiny
        }
    },
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    ymax = 100,ymin = 0,
    ytick = {0,10,...,100},
    ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
    scaled x ticks = false,
    extra x ticks = {0.06,0.2,0.6,2,60},
    ]
    \addplot [color = black, mark=none,thick, smooth] 
    coordinates 
    {
    (2, 100)
    (1.18,  99.19899337)
    (0.8,   97.38828873)
    (0.6,   94.17812423)
    (0.425, 74.5948932)
    (0.3,   38.14755708)
    (0.212, 14.63908667)
    (0.15,  4.364105082)
    (0.063, 1.242941321)
    };
    \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you are getting what you asked for... Maybe you want to replace `extra x ticks = {0.06,0.2,0.6,2,60}` with `xtick = {0.06,0.2,0.6,2,60}`?

Comment: tried that, but it is only a partial solution. this results in more evenly spaced grid. what i wanted is to have the same scale and grid but with additional ticks without 10^xx symbol. nevertheless, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default formatting of tick labels for log axes with:

```latex
log number format code/.code={%
  \pgfset{number format/fixed}%
  \pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
  ${\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$%
}
```

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
  xmin = 0.06, xmax = 60, xmode=log, domain = 0.2:60,
  height = 8 cm ,
  width = 8 cm,
  xlabel = {Sieve opening, (mm)},
  ylabel = {Sieve passing, (\%)},
  grid = both,
  yticklabel pos=left,
  ymin = 0, ymax = 100,
  ytick = {0,10,...,100},
  ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
  extra x ticks = {0.06,0.2,0.6,2,60},
  log number format code/.code={%
    \pgfset{number format/fixed}%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
    ${\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$%
  },
  % extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift=-1ex}},
  ]
  \addplot [color=black, mark=none, thick, smooth]
  coordinates
    {
      (2, 100)
      (1.18,  99.19899337)
      (0.8,   97.38828873)
      (0.6,   94.17812423)
      (0.425, 74.5948932)
      (0.3,   38.14755708)
      (0.212, 14.63908667)
      (0.15,  4.364105082)
      (0.063, 1.242941321)
    };
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: normal]

In case you want to shift the extra tick labels down a little bit, simply uncomment the line containing this:

```latex
extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift=-1ex}},
```

The output will then become as follows:

[image: extra tick labels shifted down]